# Disable fading between dialog and main activity

Tags: android, dialog

I created a little application that uses 'android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"' in it's manifest. That way, it will be displayed like a dialog, so the background will be translucent and dimmed.
During the lifecycle of the activity, there will be shown another dialog. After the dialog has been dismissed, however, the background fades in for a short time and then fades out again to match the application's theme.

I could disable this behavior by using

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

But using this will result in the dialog not dimming the activity.

Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior?

```
-Activity's background should be translucent and dimmed
-Dialog should dimm the activity's layout
-No fading when dialog is dismissed
```

Complete code:

```
public class DialogDimActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setNegativeButton("Close", null)
        .create();
    //  d.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        d.show();
    }
}
```